# How can I build a wireless webcam that transmits live images to my laptop?

Tags: microcontroller

I've got a project on facial recognition that requires the camera to be placed away from the laptop, this webcam is required to capture continuous images, and send it wirelessly to my laptop, my team has already got the source code for facial recognition (using eigen face values) only problem we have, is that an arduino mcu isn't efficient to handle these images, could you please suggest what other brand of microcontroller can I use, and how do I get along with this problem??

Comment: What resolution of images you want to transmit? What will be the distance? and Have you finalized wireless transmitter?

Comment: Look for "Raspberry Pi".

Answer (score 2):

You don't give the exact numbers regarding resolution or data transfer speeds, but at minimum you should probably be looking at something like a PIC32 or ARM Cortex M3/M4. The PIC32 route would be more friendly development setup wise, but ARM have more options and more powerful chips available.

Take a look at the PIC32 and e.g. the STM32F4 series and see if you think these will do the job. Roughly speaking, compared to an Arduino they are both rather like a jet plane vs bicycle. Also, development will obviously be a lot more involved with a more powerful 32-bit chip.